# How to detect that user is typing a message?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, xmpp, logic

For example, in chat apps when a user is composing a message, app shows `typing` icon, but if the user stopped composing **in the middle** of the message, app disappears `composing` icon.

How the app can detects that user stopped typing in the middle of composing or still typing?

For example:

**hel** (show typing icon)

*stopped typing* (hide typing icon)

**lo** (continue typing - show again)

Comment: check for keybaord is active or not and send info to API on change of status

Comment: If you are using xmpp in that case you need to send composing status to server when keyboard is active otherwise don't need to send it.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary please, read my question carefully. I asked, if the user stopped in the middle of message composing. He just stopped. Forget about keyboard

Comment: @Orkhan You can invoke your method in shouldChangeCharactersInRange.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to detect when user start typing. You can `addTarget` your `UITextField` object. When user stop typing, just set a timer in that target like that;

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

   textTimer?.invalidate()
   textTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("textFieldStopChanging:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
   print("Start typing")
}

func textFieldStopEditing(sender: NSTimer) {

   print("Stop typing")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UITextField below method may help you.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
}
```

If you are using UITextView try below

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
 }
```